# Continuity of composition of two-variables and one-variable functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I'm asked to proof the following:
Let $ f:  R^n \to R$ be continouos,
and 
$\ g: R \to R$ as well.
Proof that $\ h := g \circ f $ is continouos.
Seems to me that it follows straight from the standard definition of continuity, that is:
a function $f$ is continouos if    $$\lim_{x\to x_0}{f(x)}=f(x_0) $$
I reasoned as followed.
$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}{f(x,y)}=f(x_0,y_0)$
$\lim_{z\to z_0}{g(z)}=g(z_0)$
and, composing the functions,
$\lim_{f(x,y)\to(f(x_0,y_0)} {g[f(x,y)]}=g[f(x_0, y_0]$, but since $f(x,y) \in R$, $f(x_0, y_0)\in R $, $g$ is continouos, then $g \circ f$ is continouos. 
I've just started trying to tackle proofs and I guess my reasoning is pretty naive and I'm missing the point here, but I can't even see why it should be wrong (if it is).  Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The reason you feel unsure is probably that you don't understand what you are doing. You could try asking yourself what you understand by limit, or try to reframe your solution in the sequential definition of continuity:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_sequences

Comment: May I ask you what precisely is wrong? Am I not proving what I wanted to? If so, why? To me the one I used is a definition (or at least a necessary and sufficient condition) for continuity of a function. Sorry for bothering you, but I'd really like to know what precisely is imprecise about that.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep limits out of this argument. It is a basic fact of analysis that the composition of two continuous functions is again continuous whereas there is some small print concerning nested limits.

Assume $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, and $g$ is continuous at $y_0:=f(x_0)$. We have to prove that $h:=g\circ f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Let $g(y_0)=:z_0$. Then $h(x_0)=z_0$ as well. Let a "tolerance" $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since $g$ is continuous at $y_0$ there is an "allowance" $\delta>0$ such that
$$|y-y_0|<\delta\quad\Rightarrow\quad |g(y)-z_0|<\epsilon\ .\tag{1}$$
Now $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. This means that the values  $f(x)$ are very near $f(x_0)=y_0$ when $x$ is sufficiently near $x_0$. To be precise: There is a $\delta'>0$ such that
$$|x-x_0|<\delta'\quad\Rightarrow\quad |f(x)-y_0|<\delta\ ,$$
whereby the "tolerance" $\delta$ in this second backstep is the $\delta$ obtained in the first backstep. The new "allowance" $\delta'$ is the quantity we are after: Using $(1)$ we now have the chain
$$|x-x_0|<\delta'\quad\Rightarrow\quad |f(x)-y_0|<\delta\quad\Rightarrow\quad|g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)-z_0\bigr|<\epsilon\ .$$
As $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary this proves the continuity of $h=g\circ f$ at $x_0$.